# NodeJS Website Not Served to Local Machines from Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, networking

I have a simple NodeJS website. I serve it up locally to port 80 via:

```
npm start
```

and all is well. I can access the website through the **local ip** on phones and other devices using the same network, including the computer itself.

However, when I serve to 80 from the docker container running the npm server via

```
docker run -p 80:80
```

All seems well when I test the **local ip** on the host machine itself. But when I try to access it using phones and other devices using same network, I timeout.

I would expect the docker website to work everywhere on the local network, just the same as my non-container npm start command.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Defender Firewall was blocking the connections going to and from the container.